# Azure OpenAI Bring your own data - Semantic search not working

Tags: azure, cloud, openai-api, azure-openai

I'm trying to use Azure OpenAI BYOD feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line&pivots=programming-language-studio).

I have followed all the steps, but when choosing the search type I can only use "Keyword" and not semantic for the bot to be able to chat with me.

If I choose semantic the bot throws me an error and I don't know why. Does someone know how to enable semantic or even vector search? Both are not working.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the provided information, I have reproduced the issue.
[image]

To fix this issue, you need to select a plan of `Semantic Search`  and enable the service in your `Cognitive Search Service`.
[image]

Once you select a plan than, you'll able to get results.
[image]

Comment: Semantic search is now ['Semantic Ranker'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkmQ6.png)